# How do I programmatically generate an xml schema from a type?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to generate an xs:schema from any .net Type programmatically.  I know I could use reflection and generate it by iterating over the public properties, but is there a built in way?

Example:

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = false)] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = false)] public string LastName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)] public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
}
```

Desired Output:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Person" type="Person" />
  <xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="FirstName" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="LastName" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="PhoneNo" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I doubt there's a way to do this in the general case. Also, `[Serializable]` isn't used by the XML Serializer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this works, I guess it wasn't as ugly as it seemed:

```
var soapReflectionImporter = new SoapReflectionImporter();
var xmlTypeMapping = soapReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Person));
var xmlSchemas = new XmlSchemas();
var xmlSchema = new XmlSchema();
xmlSchemas.Add(xmlSchema);
var xmlSchemaExporter = new XmlSchemaExporter(xmlSchemas);
xmlSchemaExporter.ExportTypeMapping(xmlTypeMapping);
```

I was still hoping there was a 2 line solution out there, it seems like there should be, thanks for the tip @dtb

---

**EDIT**
Just for kicks, here's the 2 line version (self deprecating humor)

```
var typeMapping = new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Person));
new XmlSchemaExporter(new XmlSchemas { new XmlSchema() }).ExportTypeMapping(typeMapping);
```

Comment: I just found myself in a problem similar to yours. I have tried using your code, replacing `new Schema()` with an already existing `XmlSchema` variable, but it doesn't work. Could you further explain how your solution works?

Comment: Is there anything in the already existing XmlSchema?  Soap reflection importer is an internal class used by the .Net Framework for web services, I believe.  There's some msdn documentation on it.

Comment: Hi, I'm just about to reject an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/266125) because it modifies your code. You may want to check it (and associated comment out) to see if they're valid.

Answer (score 18):

I found the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680573/505457) generated an incorrect schema given some of my attributes. e.g. It ignored custom names for enum values marked with `[XmlEnum(Name="Foo")]`

I believe this is the correct way (given your using `XmlSerializer`) and is quite simple too:

```
var schemas = new XmlSchemas();
var exporter = new XmlSchemaExporter(schemas);
var mapping = new XmlReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Person));
exporter.ExportTypeMapping(mapping);
var schemaWriter = new StringWriter();
foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemas)
{
    schema.Write(schemaWriter);
}
return schemaWriter.ToString();
```

Code extracted from:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2010/05/13/using-xml-schema-import-and-export-for-xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You can programmatically invoke [**xsd.exe**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx):

1. Add **xsd.exe** as assembly reference.
2. `using XsdTool;`
3. `Xsd.Main(new[] { "myassembly.dll", "/type:MyNamespace.MyClass" });`

---

You can also use Reflector to look at the **XsdTool.Xsd.ExportSchemas** method. It uses the public  [XmlReflectionImporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlreflectionimporter.aspx),   [XmlSchemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlschemas.aspx), [XmlSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.aspx)  [XmlSchemaExporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlschemaexporter.aspx) and    [XmlTypeMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypemapping.aspx) classes to create a schema from .NET types.

Essentially it does this:

```
var importer = new XmlReflectionImporter();
var schemas = new XmlSchemas();
var exporter = new XmlSchemaExporter(schemas);

var xmlTypeMapping = importer.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Person));
exporter.ExportTypeMapping(xmlTypeMapping);

schemas.Compile(..., false);

for (var i = 0; i < schemas.Count; i++)
{
    var schema = schemas[i];
    schema.Write(...);
}                 ↑
```

You should be able to customize the output by passing a suitable writer to the [XmlSchema.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.write.aspx) method.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know you could do that. Not really what I'm looking for. The reason to do it programmatically would be to control the output.

Comment: I've actually already done that. It's sort of a cluster, I was hoping someone knew a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for: [Writing your own XSD.exe](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/01/writing-your-own-xsdexe.html)

Borrowing code from above:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

using Microsoft.CSharp;

using NUnit.Framework;

namespace XmlSchemaImporterTest
{
  [TestFixture]
  public class XsdToClassTests
  {
      // Test for XmlSchemaImporter
      [Test]
      public void XsdToClassTest()
      {
          // identify the path to the xsd
          string xsdFileName = "Account.xsd";
          string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
          string xsdPath = Path.Combine(path, xsdFileName);

          // load the xsd
          XmlSchema xsd;
          using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(xsdPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
          {
              xsd = XmlSchema.Read(stream, null);
          }
          Console.WriteLine("xsd.IsCompiled {0}", xsd.IsCompiled);

          XmlSchemas xsds = new XmlSchemas();
          xsds.Add(xsd);
          xsds.Compile(null, true);
          XmlSchemaImporter schemaImporter = new XmlSchemaImporter(xsds);

          // create the codedom
          CodeNamespace codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace("Generated");
          XmlCodeExporter codeExporter = new XmlCodeExporter(codeNamespace);

          List maps = new List();
          foreach(XmlSchemaType schemaType in xsd.SchemaTypes.Values)
          {
              maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportSchemaType(schemaType.QualifiedName));
          }
          foreach(XmlSchemaElement schemaElement in xsd.Elements.Values)
          {
              maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportTypeMapping(schemaElement.QualifiedName));
          }
          foreach(XmlTypeMapping map in maps)
          {
              codeExporter.ExportTypeMapping(map);
          }

          RemoveAttributes(codeNamespace);

          // Check for invalid characters in identifiers
          CodeGenerator.ValidateIdentifiers(codeNamespace);

          // output the C# code
          CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

          using(StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
          {
              codeProvider.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(codeNamespace, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
              Console.WriteLine(writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
          }

          Console.ReadLine();
      }

      // Remove all the attributes from each type in the CodeNamespace, except
      // System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute
      private void RemoveAttributes(CodeNamespace codeNamespace)
      {
          foreach(CodeTypeDeclaration codeType in codeNamespace.Types)
          {
              CodeAttributeDeclaration xmlTypeAttribute = null;
              foreach(CodeAttributeDeclaration codeAttribute in codeType.CustomAttributes)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(codeAttribute.Name);
                  if(codeAttribute.Name == "System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute")
                  {
                      xmlTypeAttribute = codeAttribute;
                  }
              }
              codeType.CustomAttributes.Clear();
              if(xmlTypeAttribute != null)
              {
                  codeType.CustomAttributes.Add(xmlTypeAttribute);
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Surely by now you know better than to post a link-only answer?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I debated that for few minutes before posting it, but I couldn't figure out a useful summary (other than posting the whole program out for the blog). Only risk with that is this post getting out-of-sync with any updates from there. What do you recommend?

Comment: Deleting it before it gets deleted for you would be my recommendation, unless you can come up with a summary.

Answer (score -1):

*The XML Schema Definition tool generates XML schema or common language runtime classes from XDR, XML, and XSD files, or from classes in a runtime assembly.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Running an .exe doesn't count as programmatic.