# Retrieve MIME type from Base64 encoded String

Tags: java, base64, mime

Let' say a file (e.g. myfile.jpeg) encoded in Base64 String and given to me.
There is no way I know what the file type was.
I'd like to decode the string into a file (an image in this example).
How do I know the type of the file (e.g jpeg)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify file type by base 64 encoded string of a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763533/how-to-identify-file-type-by-base-64-encoded-string-of-a-image)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, a base 64-encoded string could contain absolutely any data, so there is no way to know its file type.

To determine if it is an instance of a JPEG image, you'd need to base64-decode it, and then do something like checking its [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files), which is useful in telling you what the file *isn't*. You'd still need to do more work to determine if it is a valid JPEG image.

Answer (score 1):

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAMSURBVBhXY/j//z8ABf4C/qc1gYQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Is a sample image. Just split it with the  first slash and get array index 1. Supposing the image is coming from a trusted client.

Comment: It's not a base64 string. The real base64 starts on "iVBORw0K". Forget the before content. You don't have this on real conversion. This is exactly what we are desiring to get.