# In React native how to View base64 data in Image tag

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-webview

{"bucketName": "documents", "chunkSize": 261120, "contentType":"image/png", "encoding": "7bit", "fieldname": "Files", "filename":"profile5.png", "id": "62e8c15571dc52ad4c47de2c", "md5": null,"metadata": null, "mimetype": "image/png", "originalname":  "profile5.png", "size": 10072, "uploadDate":"2022-08-02T06:16:54.079Z"}.
this data converted into base64 data {
eyJmaWVsZG5hbWUiOiJGaWxlcyIsIm9yaWdpbmFsbmFtZSI6InByb2ZpbGUucG5nIiwiZW5jb2RpbmciOiI3Yml0IiwibWltZXR5cGUiOiJpbWFnZS9wbmciLCJpZCI6IjYyZjc3NWIwNGVmNTkyYjAzYWIwYWU5ZCIsImZpbGVuYW1lIjoicHJvZmlsZS5wbmciLCJtZXRhZGF0YSI6bnVsbCwiYnVja2V0TmFtZSI6ImRvY3VtZW50cyIsImNodW5rU2l6ZSI6MjYxMTIwLCJzaXplIjozNjE0LCJtZDUiOm51bGwsInVwbG9hZERhdGUiOiIyMDIyLTA4LTEzVDA5OjU4OjA5LjIwNloiLCJjb250ZW50VHlwZSI6ImltYWdlL3BuZyJ9
}.
and then in react native  my image as
{ <Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri:`data:image/png;base64,${source}`}}/>}
source is the base64 data but image not shown plzz any one help me i am stuck in this almost 2 weeks :(.thanks in advance:)

Comment: This isn't an image, it's metadata about an image. You would have to have a local or remote path to the image,  or the base64 data, to display it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did u solve the issue ?

Comment: @Abe thanks for your response. But i am a begginer in react native so i don't  know about metadata to base64. plz help me to sole this

Comment: Metadata just means that it is not the data you need, it only describes the data. You need a path like `http://image-host.com/image.jpg`. If you can visit the link in a browser and see the image, that's the path you need.

Comment: @Abe  i am edited this question kindly help me to sole this

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan no still not solved

Comment: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Comment: instead of source try the above base 64

Comment: check now whether works or not

Comment: @Durgadevi your base 64 is not an image its a text, how can u view as a image

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan tried using your base64 value but not image shown.

Comment: It will be a empty image

Comment: if my base64 value is an text  then how to change as a image

Comment: You can't change as image

Comment: if ur value is text , just create a text field and assign your base 64 value to that string

Comment: Did u solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As your converted `Base64` `not an image`, You cannot convert into image.

Your `Base 64 is text`. So you just create a `text field` and assign the value to it.

Comment: your answer is correct but i want to view as a image not a text. this data stored in backend (mongodb using gridfs in nodejs).

Comment: What's the use of viewing the text as image

Comment: {"bucketName": "documents", "chunkSize": 261120, "contentType":"image/png", "encoding": "7bit", "fieldname": "Files", "filename":"profile5.png", "id": "62e8c15571dc52ad4c47de2c", "md5": null,"metadata": null, "mimetype": "image/png", "originalname": "profile5.png", "size": 10072, "uploadDate":"2022-08-02T06:16:54.079Z"} if its my profile image i want to display this in my app as a image

Comment: For that you need to check your base64 file type, if your base64 is text then set into textfield if your base 64 is an image you should set into iamgeview

Comment: first find out which type of your base64 is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25763533/11789675