# BMP File Extension from Base64 String

Tags: base64

Requirement : I have a base64string   and  need to get the extension of file from that using c# , especially for BMP image type we need the extension correctly . Other images type like tiff,jpg,png ,gif and document -pdf i am able to get it correctly.

Regards
Abraham

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking file type from base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034951/checking-file-type-from-base64)

Comment: @georgy i read that post but it does not process bmp extension type . I looking forward towards that image type