# Why does C# add `xsi:type` to serialized objects? And where is the corresponding schema?

Tags: c#, xsd, xml-serialization

When I serialize a C# object (using `XmlSerializer`) that contains properties pointing to other objects that are statically typed with an *abstract class type*, the resulting XML contains elements like these:

```
<AbstractBaseClass xsi:type="ConcreteClass" />
```

So, when I don't specify `[XmlArrayItem(typeof(ConcreteClass))]` or the likes, this is intended behavior.

But since the resulting element refers to a **schema type** via the `xsi:type` attribute, there should be a means to actually produce such a schema type automatically (XSD file), right? Otherwise, any schema validator will complain that the elements refer to a non-existent type, like so (Altova XMLSpy 2016 integrated validator):

[image: Error message as shown in Altova XMLSpy]

So, either of the following should be possible:

- Is there a way to instruct the XmlSerializer to use a **different attribute** to store the concrete type?
- Is there a way to **automatically create the XSD file** that actually contains all the type information?

I am interested in both solutions, if they exist.

#### UPDATE

For the first question, there seems to exist a possibilty by using the `xsd.exe` tool from Microsoft. So that narrows the question down to the first point: Use a different attribute altogether in order to avoid the validation completely (preferred way for me).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically generate an xml schema from a type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680353/how-do-i-programmatically-generate-an-xml-schema-from-a-type)

Comment: The 'complaint' is only a warning, surely?  The validator can't know it's invalid as the schema isn't present.

Comment: I have added a screenshot showing the error. You can see my full problem in another question: [C#: XML schema validation of serialized objects causes trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540515/c-xml-schema-validation-of-serialized-objects-causes-trouble)

Comment: You can see in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sf4u1O) that the .NET validator only sees this as a warning.  You won't be able to change what attribute is used, this is how `XmlSerializer` works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fiddle. This is strange. The specification should be very clear about what is considered an error, and what a warning. Also, the XML plugin for Notepad++ complains with the same **error**.

Comment: `xsi:type` is a [w3c standard attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) by which an element can explicitly assert its type.  Support is [built into `XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx).  Since it's a standard, I don't recommend trying to rename it, and since it's built-in, I don't think it is possible, other than by implementing `IXmlSerializable` on the containing type.